# How to tune parameter max_bin in lightgbm?

Tags: lightgbm

I ran a basic example of lightgbm to test how max_bin affect the model:

```
require(lightgbm)
data(agaricus.train, package = "lightgbm")
data(agaricus.test, package = "lightgbm")
train <- agaricus.train
test <- agaricus.test

dtrain <- lgb.Dataset(data = train$data, label = train$label, free_raw_data = FALSE)
dtest <- lgb.Dataset(data = test$data, label = test$label, free_raw_data = FALSE)

valids <- list(train = dtrain, test = dtest)

set.seed(100)
bst <- lgb.train(data = dtrain,
             num_leaves = 31,
             learning_rate = 0.05,
             nrounds = 20,
             valids = valids,
             nthread = 2,
             max_bin = 32,
             objective = "binary")
```

I tried setting max_bin to 32 and 255, the two tests give the same outputs:

```
[LightGBM] [Info] Number of positive: 3140, number of negative: 3373
[LightGBM] [Info] Total Bins 128
[LightGBM] [Info] Number of data: 6513, number of used features: 107
[LightGBM] [Warning] No further splits with positive gain, best gain: -inf
[1]:    train's binary_logloss:0.644852 test's binary_logloss:0.644853 
 ......
[20]:   train's binary_logloss:0.204922 test's binary_logloss:0.204929
```

Why does the max_bin have no effect on model's training?

Comment: I think `max_bin` needs to be understood in the context of your features. It controls the number of bins/buckets for binning continuous features, so if you don't have any or they have few unique values, then you might not see much of a difference in your results.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I understand that Total Bins is something like max_bin\*features, however, in my experiment, it is always 128 (which is also very small compared to max_bin\*features). The lightgbm document does not make it clear what total bins is. I am really confused.

Comment: I agree it is not easy to figure out what is going on from the docs (for me too, at least). Are your features categorical? [Here](https://github.com/Microsoft/LightGBM/issues/1279) seems to suggest that categorical bins are dependent on memory, unlike continuous features, which operate in a conventional way. You might be better posting on the lightgbm github.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set `max_bin` during `Dataset` creation. When the `Dataset` is created the additional statistics are computed. I don't know the R implementation details, but in Python you pass it as `params={"max_bin":32}`.

Answer (score 2):

Binning is a technique for representing data in a discrete view(histogram). Lightgbm uses a histogram based algorithm to find the optimal split point while creating a weak learner. Therefore, each continuous numeric feature (e.g. number of views for a video) should be split into discrete bins.
[image]

Also, in this GitHub repo, you can find some comprehensive experiments which completely explains the effect of changing max_bin on CPU and GPU.
[image]

If you define max_bin 255 that means we can have a maximum of 255 unique values per feature. Then Small max_bin causes faster speed and large value improves accuracy.